# Web App Compatibility on Mobiles

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I am new to Mobile Development . I am developing a Web Page for Android  Mobiles..I am testing the Page using  User Agent .

Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2.1; en-ca; LG-P505R Build/FRG83) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1

Is this works only in the model which is specified or It will work well in all the Android Mobiles ?

And I want to know ,whether the web page alignments will be changes when the Mobile size changes ?

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

Govind,

I am thinking there are probably several answers to your question.  From my perspective, as a .NET developer, I would go with the method described on [this CodeProject page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/213825/ASP-net-Mobile-device-detection) to detect the "mobile-ness" of the client's browser.  If you're strictly looking in the User Agent though, look how the word "Android" shows up in there.  Just make sure your comparison code contains the word "android" without any other stuff and ignoring case and you should be fine.

As far as the size changes, your mobile device will try to do its best to show you the page you want to view.  This could mean it just "zooms out" so everything looks tiny, or maybe it only shows you a small chunk of the page in its regular size.  You should look into responsive design techniques.  All the documentation I've read on the subject says it is more beneficial to load a separate page, or at least a separate set of CSS, instead of your normal site and/or CSS for mobile browsers.  Then you can optimize the scripts and CSS and even HTML code shown in the page for these devices.

Good luck,

- Matt